How can I create multiple properties for an edge in Janus Graph?
I am using Gremlin-Python and can create edges with a single property. However, when I try to create edges with multiple properties, I encounter the following error:
Received error message '{'requestId': '006e30ec-ff77-419b-9378-3b5d241f25f7', 'status': {'message': 'No signature of method: org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.SimpleJanusGraphProperty.property() is applicable for argument types: (String, Integer) values: [timestamp, 1726492791]\nPossible solutions: propertyKey(), hasProperty(java.lang.String)', 'code': 597, 'attributes': {'stackTrace': 'groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.SimpleJanusGraphProperty.property() is applicable for argument types: (String, Integer) values: [timestamp, 1726492791]\nPossible solutions: propertyKey(), hasProperty(java.lang.String)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:72)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyGuardsFiltersAndSignatures.unwrap(IndyGuardsFiltersAndSignatures.java:161)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:321)\n\tat Script154.run(Script154.groovy:1)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:679)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:381)\n\tat java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:272)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\n', 'exceptions': ['groovy.lang.MissingMethodException']}}, 'result': {'data': None, 'meta': {}}}'

I want to create an edge which has multiple properties so I can have one to many relationships established and query based on edge properties.
This is the query that was used to create an edge.
default_db_traversal.V().has('XYZ', 'node_id', 'FLVVHKw5AamuHNmAjdYcdt').next().addEdge('causes', default_db_traversal.V().has('XYZ', 'node_id','ASIUDEYnsajdhqwdCsa').next()).property('rel_name', '').property('timestamp', 1726492791).property('value', 'ABC').property('condition', 'aosda').next();

